# How to check if a file exists with stat in visual studio c++ 2010?

Tags: c++

This is the code I have for checking if a file exists in my visual studio 2010 c++ project:

```
bool GLSLProgram::fileExists( const string & fileName )
{
    struct stat info;
    int ret = -1;

    ret = stat(fileName.c_str(), &info);
    return 0 == ret;
}
```

I am not sure why it returns false for "shaders/color.vert" when that file really exists, and shaders is a folder in my project main folder.

Can you see something wrong?

THanks

Comment: What is the value of `errno` after calling `stat`?  Is it `ENOENT` (indicating that the file could not be found), or something else?  Are you running this in the debugger?  If so, are you sure that your startup path is what you think it is (hint; probably not, set it in your project's debug settings).

Comment: If you're running from the IDE the path of the application is not the path where the application is but rather the path of where the `.proj` file is (or `.sln`). So shaders/color.vert may indeed not exist relative to that location.

Comment: yes i am running it from the IDE. Hmm so what would the correct path be?

Comment: Try running the exe outside the IDE. Build it (F7) and then go to you /Debug or /Release folder and run the exe from there. See if that fixes it.

Comment: nope :( anyway if i provide an absolute path like U:/shaders/color.vert, everything works fine, but i need to have that folder shaders in my project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so to illustrate the quirks of running from the IDE here's a little test I did. Hopefully this should help you figure out how relative paths work in VS.

So my folder hierarchy looks like this:

```
/_Sandbox
    _Sandbox.sln
    /Debug
        _Sandbox.exe
        /shaders
            color.vert
    /_Sandbox
        _Sandbox.proj
        main.cpp
```

The code looks as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    struct stat info;

    std::string path = "shaders/color.vert"; // To not I get the same behavior with "shaders\\color.vert"
    int ret = stat(path.c_str(), &info);

    ret == 0 ? std::cout << "File found." << std::endl : std::cout << "File doesn't exist." << std::endl;

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

So if I run this in the IDE, I get "File doesn't exist.", if I run this outside the IDE, I get "File Found". In order for the program to find the shader file from inside VS I have to put the shader folder like so:

```
/_Sandbox
    _Sandbox.sln
    /Debug
        _Sandbox.exe
    /_Sandbox
        /shaders
            color.vert
        _Sandbox.proj
        main.cpp
```

You can however get the code to find the folder from inside and outside the IDE. What you have to do is go to your project's settings. In "Debugging" and change "Working directory" to `$(SolutionDir)$(Configuration)\`

Hopefully this clears things up for you.